# How does FWD moves rear wheels without skidding

Tags: transmission, differential

In a RWD vehicle the rear wheels have a differential and the front have ackermann steering or so, that prevent both the front and rear wheels from slipping, but in a FWD the differential is part of the transaxle in the transmission and the rear wheels are connected separately, so how don't they skid and rub in the ground due to friction??

Comment: Yes you're right, they don't skid because of friction.

Comment: What do you mean?? If the car is turning the inside will have to spin less than the outside but they are both at the same speed, so how doesnt the inner rub with ground??

Comment: They are totally independent. One can go faster than the other. They can even be different sizes.

Comment: @FadyBasem The job of a differential is to provide equal power to both the inner and the outer wheel , in a RWD car the inner wheels will spin slower compared to outer ones, since the driven wheels are linked together so that a single engine and transmission can turn both wheels. If your car did not have a differential, the wheels would have to be locked together, forced to spin at the same speed,  in the case of a FWD car there is no power being given to the back wheels at all, they can spin at whatever speed they want, they wont cause any traction loss.